# How can I add one Target (Foundation Tool) to Copy Bundle Resources of another Target in Xcode

Tags: xcode, build-process, build, build-automation

Hy everybody,

I have two targets in one Project in Xcode. One is a foundation tool which I need in the resources Bin of the other Target, which is a Bundle App.
I am not able to add the Target one into the Copy Bundle Resources Build Phase of the Bundle App. 
Do I need to use a Copy Files Build phase and put the File out of the build/Release Folder into it?

Thank you,

Michael

Answer (score 3):

There should be a "Products" folder in your project, containing everything that would be built by your targets. You need to add the product reference for your tool (which will be in that folder) to the copy phase, not the target itself.